# How to have a linux repo/application "find itself" on the filesystem?

Tags: linux, installation, environment-variables, path

I have a repo/application/ecosystem, call it `qux`. When qux starts, it needs to `source qux-master/configure_qux.sh` or maybe hit some scripts in the repo. However, I can't guarantee where `qux-master` is located. Maybe it's at `~/foo/qux-master`. Maybe it's under `/opt`. Maybe it's in a container and right at the root, `/qux-master`. Basically, I want reliable, agnostic, programmatic access to file paths under `$QUX_REPO_DIR`.

Typically linux, typically, Ubuntu, though I'd love a more cross-POSIX-ish solution.

One thing I've tried is leveraging AppDirs/[XDG Base Dir Spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) (e.g. I'll put a link at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/qux/configure_qux.sh` back to `qux-master/configure_qux.sh`) which is okay, but it feels like there ought to be better ways.

What are my options? If this question is "too broad", are there any keywords I can search for this problem to better define what I am looking for?

Comment: The author(s) of `qux` should provide and document a way. If you're not the author then read the documentation; or tell us what `qux` is exactly, so we can read the documentation for you. Or are you the author? If you are then this is about software designing; I doubt it's on-topic here on Super User.

Comment: Usually programs are set up to search a few standard places for configuration files and then rank them in priority (compare `profile`, shell-rc, and environment files). Are they somewhat predictable? Also `which` returns results according to the current settings, or which `-a` all possible locations. But that would also mean that they are in the current `PATH` environment variable. Same goes for `whereis` but it allows setting search paths.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Yes I am the developer in this case. Maybe Software Engineering is a better platform for this question but I figure I'd try anyway. 

Fiximan - I don't want to put anything in profile/bashrc/env/PATH as that a) seems to  not be something most well-polished software does and b) seems to be an antipattern; personally I hate it when software tells me "put this in your rc file" (with the exception of shell-specific things like zsh).